# how display image laravel and filemaker?

Tags: laravel, image, filemaker

I get an image from `FileMaker` this way `https://15:201:47:78/folder/folder/jhbvkjsdbvkjsn.....`
This image path is not secure; it reports 401 Unauthorized.

My code:

```
$model = Model::get();
dd($model['image']); // output https://15:201:47:78/folder/folder/jhbvkjsdbvkjsn.....
```

Comment: That image path is actually insecure as you don't have an SSL certificate for that url. Using the domain name that is on your SSL certificate that is installed in FileMaker Server should fix the unauthorised problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. I asked my DB admin to make a new field in the database to store the base64 images.
2. Use this code in your Laravel project:

   ```
   $image = $request->image;  // your base64 encoded
   $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
   $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
   $imageName = Str:random(10).'.'.'png';
   \File::put(storage_path(). '/' . $imageName, base64_decode($image));
   ```